# can not train model using elegentrl from finrl github code

Tags: python, quantitative-finance, finrl

does anyone successfully train a model using ElegantRl from finrl GitHub code.
I'm getting an error it does not work. when I see elegantRl library code it has a lot of changes in Parameter name, method_name, class name, etc.

I tried to install elegantRl from egg which is provided in the finrl toml file. but their latest ElegantRL installed.

any update about it?